# How to determine if Javascript Q deferred() has executed all the functions in the chain

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred, q

Is it possible to know, when using the Javascript Q promise library executed all the functions registered in the chain?

I'll post a sample code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538692/callback-execution-sequence-in-javascript-retrieving-from-indexeddb) (in fact my question is follow up to that):

```
testJSCallbacks();

function testJSCallbacks(){
    var i = 0,
        promise;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //Make initial promise if one doesn't exist
        if (!promise) {
            promise = Q.fcall(getStep(i));
        }
        //Append to existing promise chain
        else {
            promise = promise.then(getStep(i));
        }
        //then function returns another promise that can be used for chaining.
        //We are essentially chaining each function together here in the loop.
        promise = promise.then(function (key) {
            //Log the output of step here
            console.log("Step 1 " + key);
            return key;
        })
        //then function takes a callback function with one parammeter (the data).
        //foo signature meets this criteria and will use the resolution of the last promise (key).
        .then(foo)
        //myCB will execute after foo resolves its promise, which it does in the onsuccess callback
        .then(myCB);
    }
}

function getStep(step) {
    return function () {
        return step;
    }
}

function foo(key) {
    //retrieve png image blob from indexedDB for the key 'key'. Assume that the database is
    //created and started properly
    var getRequest = transaction.objectStore("store").get(key),
        //Need to return a promise
        deferred = Q.defer();
    getRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var result = event.target.result;
        if(result){
            console.log("Step 2 " + key + " Found");
        }else{
            console.log("Step 2 " + key + " not Found");  
        }
        deferred.resolve(result);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}

function myCB (result){
    console.log("Step 3: " + result);
}
```

=============

If you notice in the code both foo() and myCB() will be executed 5 times.

What I want to know is, is it possible to get a callBack or notification of some sort from the Q library when the function myCB() is executed last time, essentially meaning that the queue is 'empty' and all registered/deferred functions are executed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is! Heck - I'd go as far as to say that it is the whole point of promises.

That method is called *drumroll* `.then`!

When using it, we'll also use `Q.all` in order to wait for a collection of promises. This is because you have a loop. If you didn't - all we'd need is `.then`

```
function testJSCallbacks(){
       var promises = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       ...
       promise = promise.then(function (key) {
            //Log the output of step here
            console.log("Step 1 " + key);
            return key;
        })
        //then function takes a callback function with one parammeter (the data).
        //foo signature meets this criteria and will use the resolution of the last promise (key).
        .then(foo)
        //myCB will execute after foo resolves its promise, which it does in the onsuccess callback
        .then(myCB);
        promises[i] = promise;
    }
    return Q.all(promises); // note the return statement
}
```

Then, you can hook on its completion:

```
 testJSCallbacks().then(function(results){
        // everything is complete and none of it rejected
 });
```

If you take one thing from this post - it should be to return promises from methods :). Also, instead of running myCb simply return the value and run myCb from the outside - it's more powerful :)

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm :). So, could you tell me, what is 'result' in the last callback? Here. `testJSCallbacks().then(function(results){
        // everything is complete and none of it rejected
 }); ` Yes, I know it now, that you could return promises form methods. I've known about Q only for a day, and already loving it :).

Comment: It contains an array where each item is the return value of one action in your array (of 5 actions)